# Average duration on join in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I try to calculate in DAX the average duration of a join table on lead (t1= inboundcdr , t2= orders. I want to calculate the avg duration of calls on the inboundcdr table who make orders in table orders.

This is Dax I try to run. The var join is right on the number of rows but now I want to extract the avg in this table in the duration column

```
AverageDuration = 
VAR Join = 
    FILTER(
        CROSSJOIN(inboundCdr, orders), 
        inboundCdr[lead] = orders[leadId]
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX(Join, [duration])
```

The join is right because I verify with db on countrows dax, but I don't know how to calculate de average.

I'm trying to replicate this SQL query:

```
    SELECT avg(i.duration)
FROM orders o
inner join inboundCdr i on i.lead = o.leadId
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Share a few sample rows of each table, any relationships between them, and what you are needing/expecting. Update your question above. Help us to help you.

Comment: i want to replicate this sql query on dax , find the duration of call of in inbound who had a orders: 

SELECT avg(i.duration)
FROM orders o
inner join inboundCdr i on i.lead = o.leadId 
where 1=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` is a reserved word in DAX, so rename your `VAR` and it should be good.

```
AverageDuration = 
  VAR j = 
    FILTER(
        CROSSJOIN(inboundCdr, orders), 
        inboundCdr[lead] = orders[leadId]
    )
  RETURN
    AVERAGEX(j, [duration])
```

Comment: the duration is on inbound table

Comment: Updated answer above.

Comment: Super - please Accept the answer for the benefit of all.